# Code is fine but get error in console bad argument

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am New in angular i am trying to display security question via dropdown list code is fine when it is single page but when it added to .js file at that time it display

```
Error: ng:areq
   Bad Argument
```

My Code

```
<div class="container re" ng-controller="securityQuestionController">
    <div class="row">
        <h2>Set your Security Question</h2>
        <h3>To keep your account protected please set your own security question</h3>  
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <form action="">
                <label for="peopleArraySel1">Array select 2:</label>
                <select class="form-control" ng-options="p.first for p in people" ng-model="selectedPerson">
                </select>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    app.controller("securityQuestionController",function($scope){
        $scope.people = [
            {'first': 'what is your school name'},
            {'first': 'what is collage name'},
            {'first': 'what is your father name'}
        ];
    });
```

Comment: Could you provide us a plunkr of your code?

Comment: Add **well formatted** HTML and javascript code.

Comment: Working fine here :  https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/ab8nm5o2/

Comment: thank to all code is fine when it is single page but when I add controller into my controller file at that time I got error as bad argument with controller name.

Comment: I've put the controller's code into a separate file ant it sitll works: http://plnkr.co/edit/1SLhgsU0IStjPpIakDXw.
Please provide a plunkr with non-working code.